# Preventing multiple account logins on the same device/machine in Rails 3 with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Half or more of our users fall within a specific demographic that consists of expats. Quite a few of them are couples that share the same machine but have separate accounts. For the sake of data integrity I want to close an existing session on a machine if another log in is attempted with the second user's account. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Not quite sure how i could use this info yet. Not sure of the syntax either. What object? Can you access it if you don't know whether it exists?

```
(Object) resource
```

Gets the actual resource stored in the instance variable

```
(Object) signed_in_resource
```

Returns a signed in resource from session (if one exists)

UPDATE2: Getting closer... i think. Perhaps the session cookie is the key. Wondering how i delete it at the end of a session. If one exists, if i delete it, then that kills the existing session and then the login can then begin the new one. Work on this when i get back from my lunch appt.

Comment: can't you find your happiness on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages ?

Comment: @Awea, read through the entire wiki subject list and haven't found it yet. Thanks for checking tho.

Comment: may be you was more lucky with open a new Issues on github ?

Comment: I don't understand the use case. Are they using the same machine (desktop) account? If they do and they are using the same browser you can't differentiate between them on the server side. And you can't login with another account before you logout. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ArtShayderov, yep... they are using the same machine. But they have separate accounts. We take people through personality type tests so each spouse has a separate account with separate user ids and passwords. When one has left a user session open and another has logged in... it doesn't close the prior session. It is a horrendous mess to clean up after someone has overwritten their spouses information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was so easy. Deleting the cookie terminates the session.

```
if cookies[:_Applicationname_session]
  cookies.delete(:_Applicationname_session)
end
```

'Applicationname' is whatever the application name is. It is found, among other places, in your application.rb file. e.g.:

```
module Applicationname
  class Application < Rails::Application
```

***IMPORTANT***: Don't forget the underscore that preceeds Applicationname.